# Merge 2 event actions when displaying a report

Tags: google-analytics

In an event report, is it possible to merge 2 event actions to show as just one? For example, in the below image, I'm trying to display those 2 event action rows `inline` and `free-trial` as one row `free-trial`.

[image]

What method can I use to achieve this? I've gone to 'Edit' on the report, do I then create a filter? In my filters I don't have the option to combine only include and exclude though?

Answer (score 0):

If these variables have the same Event Category value AND these are the only 2 values for Event Action, you can just look at the values for the Event Category.

If these variables have the same Event Category value BUT there could me other actions among these two, you could create a custom report. You will see the values for a category, but because of your filter they would only include the sum of these two actions.

- Dimension: Event Category
- Metrics: Total Events & Unique events
- Filter (include): `Event Category` exactly matches `<your event category>`
- Filter (include): `Event Action` matches RegEx `^(Inline|free trial)$`

[image]

If you need to this for a lot of values, you might look into making your reports in Data Studio (you can use some sort of lookup table to combine them), or adding a new custom dimension to your configuration which would hold the same value for both these actions.